# passing scene information to graphics card through a buffer to render reflections

Tags: opengl, reflection, graphics, directx, metal

I am trying to render reflections of objects in my scene onto another model in the same scene.  Here is the bit of code in my fragment function that handles specular lighting.  (I am doing this in Metal, but just a general explanation of how it's done would be helpful, I can apply it to my application from there).

```
 //Specular Color
float3 reflection = reflect(light.direction, unitNormal);
float specularFactor = pow(saturate(-dot(reflection, unitEye)), vIn.shininess);

float3 specularColor = float3(1.0, 0, 0) * vIn.specularIntensity * specularFactor;

color = color * float4(ambientColor + diffuseColor + specularColor,1);
```

`unitEye` is just the unit vector of the eye position (cam position).  The line at the bottom is just adding together my 3 colors (ambient, diffuse, and specular).  From what I understand, my current specular lighting would be converted into my reflection lighting.  For example `float3(1,0, 0, 0)` would just be whatever color is being reflected onto my object.  Here is an image of what i'm trying to accomplish for clarification.

[image]

Comment: [This article](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps) seems to be a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: thanks! i'll take a look